# Myriad pro Romanian characters

Tags: php, xml, flash, fonts

I has problem displaying T with a comma under it and S with a comma under it.

I've tried to send it encoded as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1/2 but it does not display in flash.

The PHP script creates the XML with DOMDocument class.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

I need to find a way to display these characters.

Comment: Does the font actually contain those characters in the first place?

Comment: yup, try a font that you know have them then maybe you'll find the problem :)

Comment: This font contains the romanian characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML page should begin like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Take notice at the `charset` and be aware not to override it in the `<HEAD>`.

Does your PHP code that generates the XML specifies the `charset`? It should.

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
```

Hope it helps.